# Best way to count characters in Javascript for a tweet

Tags: javascript, twitter

From the Twitter API docs ( http://dev.twitter.com/pages/counting_characters ):

the 140 chars tweet limit doesn't really count the characters but rather the bytes of the string.

How would I be able to count the bytes in a string using Javascript or does every character in my string always use 2 bytes since I set the encoding of my page to UTF-8?

Perhaps there is already a nice counter function for me to use?

Comment: Where in the linked document does it say that? All I'm reading is *"All Twitter attributes accept UTF-8 encoded text via the API."*

Comment: you defonitely need to use jQuery for that.

Comment: "the 140 chars tweet limit doesn't really count the characters but rather the bytes of the string" - where ever did you get that idea? The page (https://web.archive.org/web/20110612095727/http://dev.twitter.com/pages/counting_characters) quite clearly says "Tweet length is measured by the number of codepoints in the NFC normalized version of the text". Codepoints, not bytes.

Answer (score 21):

Actually, because of the t.co url shortener, just counting characters doesn't work anymore. Check out these two Twitter references to see how to handle shortened links:

https://support.twitter.com/articles/78124-how-to-shorten-links-urls

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-url-wrapper/how-twitter-wrap-urls

If you're looking for help on the client-side, you'll have to make a new friend with twitter-text.js

https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js

I also posted a walk-through of a function I use to count the remaining characters in a tweet

http://blog.pay4tweet.com/2012/04/27/twitter-lifts-140-character-limit/

The function looks like this

```
function charactersleft(tweet) {
    var url, i, lenUrlArr;
    var virtualTweet = tweet;
    var filler = "01234567890123456789";
    var extractedUrls = twttr.txt.extractUrlsWithIndices(tweet);
    var remaining = 140;
    lenUrlArr = extractedUrls.length;
    if ( lenUrlArr > 0 ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < lenUrlArr; i++) {
            url = extractedUrls[i].url;
            virtualTweet = virtualTweet.replace(url,filler);
        }
    }
    remaining = remaining - virtualTweet.length;
    return remaining;
}
```

The function returns the number of characters remaining, assuming that all URLs, including those shortened to less than 20 characters, have been "shortened" by t.co to 19 characters plus a space.

It assumes that twitter-text.js is being included.

Comment: Given that the number of characters of the t.co has been increased to as of earlier this year, can you update this to incorporate the increased lenght of t.co links?

Comment: With latest twitter-text.js, you can refactor that function to:    `charactersleft = function(tweet) {
    remaining = 140 - twttr.txt.getTweetLength(tweet);
    return remaining;
}
`

Answer (score 19):

Thanks [moluv00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636783/moluv00) for your answer that save me some search and put me on the right track.
I just wanted to share the way I proceeded to deal with twitter characters counting (due to tiny urls) in my app.

A [pull request](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js/commit/c469e31c541ed5bd66b9765c1d31da510d329950) as been merged on [the github repository](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js) on 2012-05-31 introducing the **twttr.txt.getTweetLength(text, options)** function that is taking consideration to t.co URLs and defined as follow :

```
twttr.txt.getTweetLength = function(text, options) {
    if (!options) {
        options = {
            short_url_length: 22,
            short_url_length_https: 23
        };
    }
    var textLength = text.length;
    var urlsWithIndices = twttr.txt.extractUrlsWithIndices(text);

    for (var i = 0; i < urlsWithIndices.length; i++) {
        // Subtract the length of the original URL
        textLength += urlsWithIndices[i].indices[0] - urlsWithIndices[i].indices[1];

        // Add 21 characters for URL starting with https://
        // Otherwise add 20 characters
        if (urlsWithIndices[i].url.toLowerCase().match(/^https:\/\//)) {
            textLength += options.short_url_length_https;
        } else {
            textLength += options.short_url_length;
        }
    }

    return textLength;
};
```

So your function will just become :

```
function charactersleft(tweet) {
    return 140 - twttr.txt.getTweetLength(tweet);
}
```

Plus, regarding [the best practices with t.co](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-url-wrapper/best-practices) we should retrieve the **short_url_length** and **short_url_length_https** values from twitter and pass them as the **options** parameter in the **twttr.txt.getTweetLength** function :

> Request GET help/configuration once daily in your application and cache the "short_url_length" (t.co's current maximum length value) for 24 hours. Cache "short_url_length_https" (the maximum length for HTTPS-based t.co links) and use it as the length of HTTPS-based URLs.

Especially knowing that **some changes in the t.co urls length will be effective on 2013-02-20** as described [in the twitter developer blog](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/upcoming-tco-changes)

Comment: I updated the t.co length in accordance with Twitter's new policy http://thenextweb.com/twitter/2012/12/06/twitter-take-away-two-of-my-precious-tweet-characters/. I see the referenced code on GitHub has already done so.

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned, twitter counts links as a string with length of 20. In our small project we ended up using following code piece :

```
function getTweetLength(input) {
  var tmp = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){tmp+="o"}
  return input.replace(/(http[s]?:\/\/[\S]*)/g, tmp).length;
};
```

In case you are using angular.js, here is a small filter you can use in your angular.js app:

```
app.filter('tweetLength', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var tmp = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){tmp+="o"}
    return input.replace(/(http[s]?:\/\/[\S]*)/g, tmp).length;
  };
});
```

And usage is as simple as :

```
Tweet length is {{tweet|tweetLength}}
```

Comment: Works great thank you. Small note, but easy fixable - Twitter now counts links as 23 characters instead of 20: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: This regex isn't quite enough for twitter's current URL identification, which treats something like foobarbaz.ba as a URL (instead of requiring the http(s):// protocol prefix). The TLD is from some lookup in their https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js/src/regexp validCCTLD.js or validGTLD.js (maybe others)

Answer (score 2):

> How would I be able to count the bytes in a string using Javascript or does every character in my string always use 2 bytes since I set the encoding of my page to UTF-8?

JavaScript counts characters and not bytes. <strike>You don't have a problem at all.</strike>

```
"嘰嘰喳喳".length == 4
"Twitter".length == 7
```

Update: The above only is correct for strings that contain nothing but characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP).

Determining string length is not quite so simple when the string contains characters from outside the BMP (like Emoji) or combining marks. The following blog post discusses the matter exhaustively, reading it is highly recommended: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Comment: JavaScript counts UTF-16 code units, but the Twitter docs require codepoints after normalisation.

Comment: Can you give me an example string where Javascript would report a different length than Twitter?

Comment: Any non-Basic Multilingual Plane character would be counted as two characters by JS but one by Twitter. A combination of a base character and a combining diacritical mark would be reported as having a different length from a single precomposed character by JavaScript, but not by Twitter.

Comment: Ah, you are right, thanks! I found this: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode. Funny though, that none of the other answers even mention this peculiar point.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter counts the following character ranges as 1 char:

```
U+0000..U+10ff, U+2000..U+200D, U+2010..U+201F, U+2032..U+2037
```

Everything else is counted as 2 chars.

Considering that Javascript encodes astral planes (U+10000 and above) as pairs of UTF-16 surrogates in the U+D800..U+DFFF range (so that `"".length == 2`), I've come up with the following

```
function count_tweet_chars(str){
  str = str.normalize('NFC');
  var char2 = str.match(/[^\u0000-\u10ff,\u2000-\u200D,\u2010-\u201F,\u2032-\u2037,\uD800-\uDfff]/g) || [];
  return str.length + char2.length;
}
```

Note that the above doesn't include replacement of urls by t.co 23-character urls, and also it doesn't count correctly multi-character graphemes like