# Handling Character count for twitter post which includes URL

Tags: jquery

I am allowing users to post comments from my site to directly twitter using API. I am using same character counter as twitter. I am allowing users to enter 140 character and as user starts typing in, I am reducing the character count. I am also allowing users to enter more than 140 character but he can not submit the comment if count is more than 140 characters.

All above functionality is working fine. The problem come in picture when user enter the any URL e.g. http://www.google.com

If you type "the http://www.google.com" in twitter the it counts it 24 character and shows 116 char remaining.

How could I handle this? If I allow user to type http://www.google.com with 119 more characters then I can not post it to twiiter. It is returning below error message-

```
 REST Response Error: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-   load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: ^
```

How twitter count the character of a URL??

I am using the below class for character counter -

http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas which I have cusomized as below -

```
 (function($) {

$.fn.charCount = function(options){

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {    
        allowed: 140,       
        warning: 25,
        css: 'counter',
        counterElement: 'span',
        cssWarning: 'warning',
        cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
        counterText: ''
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

    function calculate(obj){
        var count = $(obj).val().length;
        var strButton = "";
        if(count >= 1){
            strButton = "1";
            $('#fcButtonsAct').show();
            $('#fcButtonsDis').hide();
        }else{
            $('#fcButtonsAct').hide();
            $('#fcButtonsDis').hide();
        }
        var myObj = $('#myCharCounter');

        var available = options.allowed - count;
        if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
            $(myObj).addClass(options.cssWarning);
        } else {
            $(myObj).removeClass(options.cssWarning);
        }
        if(available < 0){
            strButton = "1";
            $(myObj).addClass(options.cssExceeded);
            $('#fcButtonsAct').hide();
            $('#fcButtonsDis').show();
        } else {
            $(myObj).removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
        }

        $(myObj).html('<div style="float:right;line-height:28px;"><i>' + available + ' </i></div>');
    };

    this.each(function() {
        calculate(this);
        $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this)});
        $(this).change(function(){calculate(this)});
    });

 };

 })(jQuery);
```

and getting done it by calling below function

```
$("#txtuserstatus").charCount({
      allowed: 140,
      warning: 10,
      counterText: '',
      counterElement: 'div'
 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there by any chance of Java implementation of this?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you should check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245487/best-way-to-count-characters-in-javascript-for-a-tweet). In particular you should probably use a library called twitter-text.

https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js